# wordpress contact form integration with CRM

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress contact us form in divi and i need it to be connected with ZOHO CRM so that the leads can be stored.I have embeded the ZOHO FORM but it looks very pale in comparison to the form which i created in divi wordpress.so how can i put same functionality of zoho form in wordpress contact form

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You need to post your code examples to get help here. Like your CSS and HTML for the form

Answer (score 0):

Look at the embedded code from Zoho CRM - it's using a simple table to lay out the form. So what you have to do is get rid of all these table related components and use some css to style your fields.

Here's an example of how I styled the email field:

```
<p><input style="background:#F2F2F2; width: 100%; font-family: Roboto; font-size:16px; padding: 10px 10px; line-height: 24px;" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></p>
```

The thing to be careful about is not to touch at the portion of code tagged with " `<!-- Do not remove this code. -->"`

Answer (score -1):

It's complicated to have the same GUI for Zoho Forms but alternatively you can use available plugins for that take look at following solutions

**Available Plugins**

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-zoho-crm/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/zoho-crm-integrator/
http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/zoho-crm/
```

**Zoho Wordpress Integration Guide**

```
https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/help/wordpress-integration.html
```

**Use Third Party Connector**

```
https://zapier.com/zapbook/wordpress/zoho-crm/
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could take the integration form's HTML from one of the plugins or Zoho itself, then generate a "nice looking" but useless form with Divi. Compare the two HTML outputs and copy over the classes & IDs used by the theme's CSS from the Divi form to the appropriate elements in your Zoho form.

You should end up with a Zoho form that is visually similar to a Divi form. I'm not familiar with either forms' markup unfortunately, so can't tell if this is going to be an easy or difficult task.

Good luck!